# Weird Axios Network Error with seemingly error-free code

Tags: python, reactjs, axios, general-network-error

I am trying to use react to get data from an API (Python, I'm hosting it on the same machine).

API Code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def all_data():
all_data = "Hello"
return jsonify({
'data':all_data,
'message':"success"
}), 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

React code(Didn't include the `render()`):

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listData:[],
      url:"http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
  getPlanets=()=>{
    console.log("Axios called")
    const url = this.state.url;
    console.log(url)
    axios.get(url).then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data)
      return this.setState({listData:response.data})
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error.message)
      Alert.alert(error.message);
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getPlanets();
  }
}
```

I'm always getting `Network Error` for the `console.log(error.message)`.
I'm also getting a larger `Error: "Network Error" in Error: Network Error <<     at e.exports (axios.js:3:7286) <<     at d.onerror (axios.js:3:6270)` for `console.log(error)`.

Simultaneously, I got two weird error messages in my API:

```
code 400, message Bad request version ('localhost\x00\x17\x00\x00ÿ\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00')
```

```
"▬♥☺☻☺☺ü♥♥ÆuaTÁS¾eài ¸ ²`½‼/cùCf{&*½(¨qh↓(â®z↨Ó ×D ÚÚ‼☺‼☻‼♥À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À‼À¶úú♫♀                                                                   l
ocalhost↨ÿ☺☺" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

Help?

I've tried looking through a lot of websites for the problem, but they all just suggested adding the `http://` prefix to my url, which I had already done. I'm also using Python for the API and not NodeJS, so I don't need to use CORS. I just couldn't find a relevant fix anywhere.

Comment: Did you try `"http://localhost:5000/"` or atleast giving a route path for test purpose ?

Comment: Just tried it. No success. :(

Comment: Since today when I reinstalled axios with `npm`, I get with some requests weird characters - `�\u001b\u0002\u0000dߜ�骧\u0001` as result. With `fetch` api it always works. Maybe axios does not work properly right now? Some axios requests not dependant on get and post work though. Did not find the reason.